# QueryOver Many to Many with a single SQL join

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I've got 2 entities, linked many-to-many. (Product & User)
I want to restrict Products by Users:

```
User userAlias = null;
query.JoinAlias(product => product.Users, () => userAlias)
  .Where(() => userAlias.Id == currentUser.Id);
```

It's generated SQL code:

```
SELECT this_.Id as y0_
FROM   [Product] this_
       inner join UserToProduct users5_
         on this_.Id = users5_.Product_id
       inner join [User] useralias3_
         on users5_.User_id = useralias3_.Id
....
```

In "Where" i use only user_id and i don't need second join.

How I can write the query(by QueryOver) with a single SQL join ?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to accomplish this in QueryOver without going through the join table.

Comment: Maybe you're right, I haven't found a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help? I have a similar setup with UsersRoles

```
Role roleAlias = null;
var roles = _session.QueryOver<UsersRole>().JoinAlias(x => x.Role, () => roleAlias, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin).Where(
            x => x.User.UserId == userId).List();
```

produces the following:

```
SELECT this_.UsersRolesId         as UsersRol1_32_1_,
       this_.UserId               as UserId32_1_,
       this_.RoleId               as RoleId32_1_,
       rolealias1_.RoleId         as RoleId27_0_,
       rolealias1_.RoleName       as RoleName27_0_,
       rolealias1_.Active         as Active27_0_,
       rolealias1_.DateCreated    as DateCrea4_27_0_,
       rolealias1_.LastUpdated    as LastUpda5_27_0_,
       rolealias1_.RoleSettingsId as RoleSett6_27_0_
FROM   UsersRoles this_
       left outer join Roles rolealias1_
         on this_.RoleId = rolealias1_.RoleId
WHERE  this_.UserId = 'a7eec4eb-21cc-4185-8847-a035010e779f' /* @p0 */
```

Comment: So to clarify, the OP needs to create a join entity?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't have entity for relation "UserToProduct", i use it implicitly, and i wouldn't to create it.

Comment: So is the UserId stored in the products table I am assuming? please post your entites next time maybe:)